# Split column based on delimiter and considering the content

Tags: python, pandas, split

I need to split the content of a pandas column that contain some 'structured' data in many other columns based on content.

The strucure is "column_name1"/"value1"/"column_name2"/"value2"/...

For instance, the word "subscriptions" will become the name of column, and the "sub-id", "sub-id2" will be the values.

Transform this:

| ResourceID |
| --- |
| /subscriptions/sub-id/resourceGroups/rg-name/providers/Microsoft.MachineLearningServices/workspaces/work-ml/providers/Microsoft.EventGrid/extensionTopics/default |
| /subscriptions/sub-id2/resourceGroups/rg-name2/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/name-sqlserver/databases/name-BD |

Into this:

| subscriptions | resourceGroups | providers | workspaces | servers | providers | extensionTopics | databases |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| sub-id | rg-name | Microsoft.MachineLearningServices | work-ml | NaN | Microsoft.EventGrid | default | NaN |
| sub-id2 | rg-name2 | Microsoft.Sql | NaN | name-sqlserver | NaN | NaN | name-BD |

Any help would be very apreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each row looks like: `/key1/val1/key2/val2/...` so split each part, zip keys and values then create a dict. Finally, use `pd.DataFrame.from_records` to create your expected dataframe:

```
data = df['ResourceID'].str.strip('/').str.split('/') \
                       .apply(lambda x: dict(zip(x[::2], x[1::2])))
out = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data)
print(out)

# Output
  subscriptions resourceGroups            providers workspaces extensionTopics         servers databases
0        sub-id        rg-name  Microsoft.EventGrid    work-ml         default             NaN       NaN
1       sub-id2       rg-name2        Microsoft.Sql        NaN             NaN  name-sqlserver   name-BD
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to the other answer by @Corralien, you could do this using `split`'s `expand` parameter:

```py
df = df["ResourceID"].str.split("/", expand=True)
out = df[df.columns[2::2]]
out.columns = df.loc[0, df.columns[1::2]]
```